# How to connect to MYSQL database manually with Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to connect to a MySQL database without adding it to database.yml. How can I connect and run a query on that database?

I understand I need to do something like this, but what's the code for actually making the connection to the specific IP/port first?

```
query = "SELECT 1"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

Comment: Just using ActiveRecord or through the mysql2 gem?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma either works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`

Example from documentation:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :username => "myuser",
  :password => "mypass",
  :database => "somedatabase"
)
```

From:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class

Comment: set conn = to that. Then conn.execute(query) ?

Comment: My guess is that you need to use the code above first on its own, and then you can use ActiveRecord::Base.connection as you did in the question. Does that work?